# Heroku rake db:migrate failing without error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am pushing a rails application from GitHub to Heroku. The push command succeeds without issue. However, when I run DB migrate, one migration is run successfully, then two further tables are created. The process exits when these tables are created and no further migrations occur.

I can confirm that the users table is created. Rerunning the migration gives the same result

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on glacial-dawn-9135... starting, run.9094 (Free)
Running rake db:migrate on glacial-dawn-9135... connecting, run.9094 (Free)
Running rake db:migrate on glacial-dawn-9135... up, run.9094 (Free)
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:22.103433 #4] DEBUG -- :    (6385.0ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:22.211403 #4] DEBUG -- :    (103.6ms)  CREATE TABLE "ar_internal_metadata" ("key" character varying NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "value" character varying, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:22.215555 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.0ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(4036276764900377970)
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:22.526092 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
I, [2019-06-05T21:05:22.527894 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to DeviseCreateUsers (20190604184418)
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:22.532709 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.5ms)  BEGIN
== 20190604184418 DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:users)
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:24.988378 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2450.7ms)  CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" bigserial primary key, "email" character varying DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" character varying DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" character varying, "reset_password_sent_at" timestamp, "remember_created_at" timestamp, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
   -> 2.4556s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:25.086000 #4] DEBUG -- :    (42.8ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "index_users_on_email" ON "users"  ("email")
   -> 0.0974s
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:25.120170 #4] DEBUG -- :    (29.5ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "index_users_on_reset_password_token" ON "users"  ("reset_password_token")
   -> 0.0343s
== 20190604184418 DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (2.5877s) =======================

D, [2019-06-05T21:05:25.127740 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Create (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20190604184418"]]
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:25.131447 #4] DEBUG -- :    (3.4ms)  COMMIT
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:25.142898 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:25.153905 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.6ms)  BEGIN
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:25.157339 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Create (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "ar_internal_metadata" ("key", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "key"  [["key", "environment"], ["value", "production"], ["created_at", "2019-06-05 21:05:25.154649"], ["updated_at", "2019-06-05 21:05:25.154649"]]
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:25.161052 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.9ms)  COMMIT
D, [2019-06-05T21:05:25.163289 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.9ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(4036276764900377970)

user@Desktop MINGW64 /c/PathMed (development)
```

I have 12 migration files. On my local machine (windows) migrations occur without issue.

Edit: here is the output of rake db:migrate:status

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate:status

database: da599721qov2v0

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
D, [2019-06-06T06:46:29.454045 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
   up     20190604184418  Devise create users
```

Furthermore, running rake db:schema:load instead of db:migrate results in the same thing, one table migrated.

Update 2: I took the schema.rb and migrations and created a blank rails app using them. I was able to push to heroku and run the migrations without a problem. I suspect it's a configuration issue somewhere or possibly relating to my seeds.rb file. Anyone have any thoughts as to why, or do I need to make the entire project again from scratch?

Update 3: Gave up, created a new project from scratch, generated models from scratch using migrations and then copied across all the application logic. It all works fine now.

Comment: That doesn't look like failure. How many migrations do you see in your `db/migrate/` directory?

Comment: run "heroku run rake db:migrate:status" command to see which tables have been migrated and which have not. The tables with "up" status  are  migrated and those with "down" status are yet

Comment: Thanks for the assistance guys. There are 12 migrations in my migrations directory. The output of db:migrate:status is in the original post. Something weird is definitely going on. I've also tried destroying and creating heroku instances, the problem persists.

Comment: You see 12 migrations _on Heroku_ in your `db/migrate/` directory? Or just locally?

Comment: Locally. I can also see them in GitHub. I didn't check locally on heroku as I didn't know how. In any case I solved the problem by recreating the entire rails app from scratch and adding everything back piece by piece.